# jQuery accordion for multiple nested lists

Tags: jquery, navigation, accordion

I'm struggling to incorporate the second nested list of my menu so that they can open onclick. Below is my code.

Also, how can I make it so clicking to expand a list doesn't trigger any other events? Right now if you click them, my entire menu slides closed from another script (this is for a mobile responsive menu) So if my menu-item li has a nested list, I want the click to ONLY open or close its nested list and do nothing else.

http://jsfiddle.net/notanothercliche/36vCh/

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-menu">

    <li class="menu-item>Home</li> <!-- end Home menu-item -->

    <li class="menu-item>Properties

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li class="menu-item>Dubai

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li class="menu-item>Residential

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                <li class="menu-item>Apartments</li>

                <li class="menu-item>Villas</a></li>

            </ul> <!-- end Residential dropdown-menu -->

                </li> <!-- end Residential menu-item -->

        </ul> <!-- end Dubai dropdown-menu -->

        </li> <!-- end Dubai menu-item -->

    </ul> <!-- end Properties dropdown-menu -->

    </li> <!-- end Properties menu-item -->

</ul> <!-- end menu-menu -->
```

Comment: Be aware that anchors are required to have non-empty `href` attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to work so hard. There's probably no need to manipulate classes like you are.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/36vCh/6

```
jQuery("#menu-menu a").on("click", function (e) {
    if (jQuery(this).parent().has("ul")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Note that I added a few missing quotes and required href attributes.